# Get values on click from Google visualisation datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

Here I have a Google vizualisation datatable. I need to get values from table row.

CODE:http://jsfiddle.net/AVHY8/11/

I currently write:

```
 new google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
        google.visualization.events.addListener(table.getChart(), 'select', function () {
            var selection = table.getChart().getSelection();
            // iterate over all selected rows
            for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
                alert(selection[i].row);
            }
        });
    });
```

So now when I click on row I just get number of row... but how I can get values of that row?

I try with `alert data.getValue[(selection[i].row)];`
but it doesn't work? Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I also try with this code:

```
 // Add our selection handler.
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', selectHandler);

// The selection handler.
// Loop through all items in the selection and concatenate
// a single message from all of them.
function selectHandler() {
  var selection = table.getSelection();
  var message = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
    var item = selection[i];
    if (item.row != null && item.column != null) {
      var str = data.getFormattedValue(item.row, item.column);
      message += '{row:' + item.row + ',column:' + item.column + '} = ' + str + '\n';
    } else if (item.row != null) {
      var str = data.getFormattedValue(item.row, 0);
      message += '{row:' + item.row + ', column:none}; value (col 0) = ' + str + '\n';
    } else if (item.column != null) {
      var str = data.getFormattedValue(0, item.column);
      message += '{row:none, column:' + item.column + '}; value (row 0) = ' + str + '\n';
    }
  }
  if (message == '') {
    message = 'nothing';
  }
  alert('You selected ' + message);
}
```

It doesn't work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSFiddle the `data` array is inside the `drawVisualization` function, so the event handlers don't have access to it. If you put it in global scope (or in a closure that includes the event handlers) it should work.

Edit:
Aha, the index of the selection refers to the current datatable, which is altered by the ControlWrapper. What you can do is instead of `data.getValue(..)` do `table.getDataTable().getValue(..)`.

Also note that you don't deselect the previously selected rows, leading to some confusion.

Comment: Also read the documentation of the getValue function, it needs two parameters. See here for my version of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AVHY8/23/

Comment: ok, this work I implement here: http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/10/edit , but I use filter then I dont get right values on input fields ... WHY>

Comment: try to type etc. "m" into search field and then to click on edit button, you will not get right values !!! WHY?

Comment: I try here: http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/11/edit but again dont work... How I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["table"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Full Time Employee');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, 10],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  20],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, 38],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  20]
        ]);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

        table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true });

      
            $("#table_div table tbody tr td").click(function () {
                alert($(this).html());
            });
      
      }
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table_div">
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Prashant, in future please consider adding an explanation to your answer, which accompanies the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use events listners to do that.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function () {
    selectHandler(table);
});

function selectHandler(myTable) {
    var selectedItem = myTable.getSelection()[0];
    if (selectedItem) {
       console.log(data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0))
    }
}
```

The number in front of the "selectedItem.row" is the column value you want to get.